# How can I update form which is wrap within DIV tag using jQuery/ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can update the full form with jQuery/Ajax request but how can update a certain fields which is wrap within a div.

For example:

```
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="update_certain_fields"> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Family name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>given name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gname" id="gname"/></td>
</tr> 
</div>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------> 
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>Email private</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pemail" id="pemail"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Change" id="upload"/></td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    var cid=$('#cdid').val();
    $("#loading-image").show();


    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails2.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data){                    
          getDetails(cid);  
          $("#loading-image").hide(); //hide loading          
          $("#success").html(data);
            document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();


        },

    //  complete: function(){
     // $("#loading-image").hide(); //hide loading here
    //},

        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

So is it possible to update only those fields which wrap with `class=update` ? Can you give me an example for that ?

Thank you.

Comment: _So is it possible to update only those fields which wrap with class=update_ Answer is __Yes__

Comment: @Satpal can you tell me how can i do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by `update`? Are you missing a closing `</div>`? -- not being picky; we just pay too much attention to detail.

Comment: Do you mean `submit`?

Comment: @user3558931 `update` is a class name which warp few html form fields. So I want to update those fields which is wrap within a Div tag with the class name `update`

Comment: So you want to add the `update` class to all the input fields in the `<div class="update"/>`, right? Why didn't you say so? :)

Comment: @ShaunakD No. I've a full html form. Now I want to update only few fields with jquery/Ajax which is wrap within a div tag with the class name `update`.

Comment: @user3558931 No I don't want to add `update` class to all input fields. I Can update the full form using jquery/ajax with php. Now i want to update few fields within the form which is wrap with `div` tag with class name `update`

Comment: 'A few fields' is quite precise. How do you know which ones? See my answer; only the fields in the `div` are affected not **all fields**. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your markup:

**Firstly,** your nesting of the div is just not proper.

**Secondly,** event if you were to use proper nesting, a `div` cannot be in a `table` unless it is in a `td` or a `th`.

**Thirdly,** please define precisely what you mean by "I want to update", otherwise you'll not have an answer in this generation.

Therefore I would suggest to do away with the div and use traversal.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Family name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>given name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gname" id="gname"/></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>Email private</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pemail" id="pemail"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Change" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>  
</table>
</form>


$('table').find('tr:lt(2)').find(':text') ......
```

Comment: I don't want to add class to input field. I want to update a certain html fields which is wrap within a div tag.

Comment: So I can get all html input fields value which is within a div tag with class name update.

Comment: I'm updating a user profile using Jquery/Ajax with php. so now I want to update certain fields which is wrap within a div tag with the class name `update`.

Comment: Please say what you want to do without using the word `update`? Help me help you.

Comment: Well,I'm explaining it again. I've a Html form where 6 input fields exits. Now I can edit/update full html form using Jquery/Ajax with php. Ok fine. NOW, I want to update only 3 fields which is wrap within a div tag. So If i get the value of those 3 fields which are wrap within a div tag then I can edit those 3 fields using jquery/ajax with php. So my questions how can i get those 3 fields value using jquery/ajax ?

Comment: Maybe if you show us how you're able to update the full html, we might be able to understand what it is you're doing. Is that fair?

Comment: Ok..I'm updating my question.

Comment: Actually i want to update first 2 fields which is `family name` and `given name`. How can update those 2 fields without pressing any button. Can I do this with jquery mouseenter function ? if so, how can do this ? or is there any way to update those 2 fields without pressing any button. I'm sorry for my fault.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it does not help. Sorry, I am not able to help you further.